# What's the best data structure for grouping and ungrouping shapes

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I need to implement group/ungroup functionality in a graphic application. The aim is to be similar to the group/ungroup functionality in Adobe Illustrator or Microsoft PowerPoint.

Groups can be nested (i.e.: a group can contain both elements and other groups, which in turn contain elements or groups)

I am wondering what is the best data structure for doing that.

It should be possible to tell quickly:

- whether an element is in a group
- its siblings in the widest group that contains it

I am thinking of something like this:

```
{
    groups: {
        g1: ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'],
        g2: ['n4', 'n5', 'g1'],
        g3: ['g2', 'n6', 'n7']
    },
    nodes {
        n1: 'g1',
        n2: 'g1',
        n3: 'g1',
        n4: 'g2',
        n5: 'g2',
        g1: 'n1',
        g2: 'g3',
        n6: 'g3',
        n7: 'g3'
    }
}
```

With `group` containing the groups themselves, and `nodes`acting as a lookup table to tell if a node is in a group. I could tell nodes and groups apart from their ID's (nodes are always numbers). Recursing through groups would provide lists of siblings.

This would be encapsulated in an object that would then handle group, ungroup and checking - in JavaScript.

Is this sane? Is there a better way?

Comment: Create a `node` class and a `group` class that will internally save a collection of nodesor groups as an array. Nodes (as well as groups) could have a `in_group` property that will be either false by default or if removed from a group, or a reference to the group it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a tree structure? Using Nodes like so:

```
function Node (value, parent) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];
  this.parent = parent || null
}

Node.prototype.addChild = function (node) { … }

Node.prototype.traverse = function (fx) {
  fx(this);
  this.children.forEach(function (child) {
    child.traverse(fx);
  });
}
…

var root = new Node({id: 100}, null);
```

With that you add more pointers/references for faster tree traversals. To test if a Node is in a group, you just need to check if its parent is not null. Many other tests/query can be performed by simple tree traversals.